# Onchanges Angular4 not working

Tags: angular

i have the code working onInit but not onChanges.

here is code from component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class FetchDataComponent implements OnChanges  {
 site: string[] = [];
 @Input() values: string = "https://angular.io";    

 onEnter(value: string) { this.values = value; } // this is to get value from input field

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

 var slog = this.values;

 this._httpService.get('/api/websites/?angular='+slog).subscribe(values => {
            this.site= values.json() as string[];
        });
}
```

i tried to follow the guide https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example which is targeting angular 4.

the same code was working with onInit but i need it to monitor the changes made onChanges

Comment: Can you add the code where you change the inputs of this component?

Comment: So you meant to say that `ngOnChanges()` is not firing? Did you try adding `console.log()` and checked?

Answer (score 0):

when data-bound changes on the input properties on the component the angular life cycle hook method like ngOnChanges will called automatically.

Please check these stackblitz URL 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpshn4?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployee%2Femployee.component.ts

changes on the input property and see the console how ngOnChanges will called

Answer (score -1):

here is an example this might help you

**component.html**

```
<select placeholder="A" (selectionChange)="appslctchange($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
 appslctchange(changeEvent) 
         {
          alert("It Works");
         }
```